# Hover and nested list : which element is being hovered?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, hover

I have a nested list representing categories and subcategories where the depth is unknown, it is created with data from a database.

What I am trying to do is to display a little image, a cross, next the category being hovered.

Problem is I can't reliably differentiate if it is an ancestor li element or a child which is being hovered because the "mousein" event isn't fired again when I go back to a parent category from a subcategory.

My current code is :

**Html example**

```
<ol class="innerCenter" id="bdc_categories">
    <form action="?function=base_connaissances&amp;onglet=2" method="POST" id="" name="">
        <li>Hardware<img class="hidden" src="image/supp.png">
            <ol>
                <li>Ecran<img class="hidden" src="image/supp.png">
                    <ol>
                        <li>Alimentation<img class="hidden" src="image/supp.png"></li>
                        <li>Dalle<img class="hidden" src="image/supp.png"></li>
                    </ol>
                </li>
                <li>Disque dur<img class="hidden" src="image/supp.png"></li>
            </ol>
        </li>
        <li>Test<img class="hidden" src="image/supp.png"></li>
        <li>Test<img class="hidden" src="image/supp.png"></li>
        <li>Test<img class="hidden" src="image/supp.png"></li>
        <li>Ajouter une catégorie...<img class="hidden" src="image/supp.png"></li>
        <li>Software<img class="hidden" src="image/supp.png">
            <ol>
                <li>Excel<img class="hidden" src="image/supp.png"></li>
            </ol>
        </li>
    </form>
    <form action="?function=base_connaissances&amp;onglet=2" method="POST" id="" name="">
        <input type="hidden" value="NULL" name="idCategSup">
        <input type="text" value="Ajouter une catégorie..." name="lib_categ">
        <input type="submit" value="Ok">
    </form>            
</ol>
```

**Javascript**

```
$("#bdc_categories").on('mouseleave', '', '', function(){$("#bdc_categories li").removeClass('is-hover'); $("#bdc_categories li").children('img').css({"visibility": "hidden"});});
    $("#bdc_categories li").hover(function (event) {
        event.stopPropagation();

        if($(event.target).is('li')){
        $("#bdc_categories li").removeClass('is-hover');
        $("#bdc_categories li").children('img').css({"visibility": "hidden"});

        $(event.target).addClass('is-hover');
        $(event.target).children('img').css({"visibility": "visible"});



        var tar = $(event.target);
        while ($(tar.parent('ol').parent('li')).length) {
            tar = $(tar.parent('ol').parent('li'));
            $(tar).addClass('is-hover');
            //$(tar).children('img').css({"visibility": "hidden"});
        }
    }

    }, function (event) {
        event.stopPropagation();

        $(event.target).removeClass('is-hover');




        $("#bdc_categories li").not(".is-hover").children('img').css({"visibility": "hidden"});
        $("#bdc_categories .is-hover").children('img').css({"visibility": "visible"});
        $("#bdc_categories .is-hover").parent('ol').parent('li').children('img').css({"visibility": "hidden"});

    }
```

It is almost working but I am sure there is a better way to achieve this?
And there's still a little problem : if I go from a "Test" li to the Hardware li, the image doesn't appear...I think it's because the mousein event is fired on the ol element, even if I am not on a li...

Any help would be appreciated!

Answer (score 0):

Aren't you missing a `);` at the very end of your JS code? When I fix that and try this in JSFiddle, it works.

Is [this](http://jsfiddle.net/tmb33mkh/) not what you're looking for?

Comment: Just a mistake when I pasted my code but try to go from a test li to the hardware li (without hovering the subcategories), the image won't show up

Comment: @Nehluxhes thanks for letting me know. Still, it works for me. I can go from a test `li` to the hardware one and the images show up :)

Comment: Sorry, I should have added you must not leave the main <ol> either, just go vertically from a test <li> to the hardware <li> (stay in the padding)

Comment: Also don't go over the numbers! Yeah that's a very specific bug :D Just from test to hardware, vertically. Tested with IE11, Chrome and Firefox and I have the bug.

Comment: Oh, right! Well, I can't see why it wouldn't work from a technical perspective.  It should still trigger a new event when you move upwards through the `<ol>`. Sorry @Nehluxhes, I'll delete my answer :)